# cross compiling with Eclipse on linux and eclipse on windows?

Tags: c++, linux, embedded, arm, cross-compiling

I am pretty much new to embedded device programming world so pardon my ignorance if any.

I am cross compiling a C++ program on arm architecture with eclipse on ubuntu.
Then i have to burn the code and see the output with the device that has a linux kernel in it.

Then i came across a tutorial about cross compiling C++ program on arm architecture with eclipse on Windows. So my question is, Can i run this program (from windows) on my embedded device which has a linux kernel in it????

Thanks
A

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a cross compiler, then the answer is yes. It should produce a linux libraries and executive file. You might need to adjust the files parameters (like set permissions and execute flag).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

eclipse is a great tool, especially when coupled with gcc.  You can definitely use a ready-built compiler to extend eclipse as long as that compiler is available for Windows.

Here is a link to some documentation on how to change the toolchain in an eclipse project -
http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_prop_build_toolchain.htm

Comment: Okay, thanks for your response, but i just to confirm myself one more time before heading on to get this work completed. Let me put it in different words this time
The output after cross compiling (arm architecture using eclipse) in linux AND the output after cross compiling (arm architecture using eclipse) in windows would be same?? i.e. I will be able to run the "cross compiled arm architecture in windows using eclipse"'s output on a linux running device????????

Comment: Um, as I understand your question....  Yes, the output will be the same if you're using the same compiler.  Unless the toolchain you have comes with an emulator, you won't be able to run the output binary on Windows - which is the same as if you were cross-compiling the binary on Linux.  You won't be able to *run* the output with eclipse.